# Foundation Modal window options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, zurb-foundation

I am working on asp.net webform application(btn Submit). I am showing a success message and which will be a 'modal window' with some options in there.

I am stuck on how to pass a callback function when the 'closed' option is triggered.

I have had a look on foundation at the options and have tried these examples.

```
$(function () {
 $('.modal').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').reveal();
    if (closed) {
        (function () {
            window.location.replace("http://some url/");
        });
    };
 });
});
```

The above doesn't work just does nothing.

```
$(function () {
 $('.modal').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').reveal({
        closed: window.location.replace("http://google.com/")
    });
 });
});
```

This just goes straight to google. :)

```
$(function () {
 $('.modal').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').reveal("closed", function() {
    window.location.replace("http://google.com/")});
 });
});
```

Any Ideas would be nice good thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook it up during initialization of you reveal, and you need to do it before you initialize the entire library of Foundation.

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', {    
    closed: function () {
        window.location.replace("http://google.com/");
    }
});
$(document).foundation();
```